# Get correct results from the database in Django

Tags: python, django

I have three Django models as follows:

```
class NewFeature(models.Model):
    application = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    stop = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(to=Group)

class NewFeatureDetails(models.Model):
    new_feature = models.ForeignKey(to=NewFeature)
    culture = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False, default='en')
    text = models.TextField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, blank=False, null=False)

class NewFeatureRead(models.Model):
    new_feature = models.ForeignKey(to=NewFeature)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Thus `start` and `stop` in `NewFeature` model could be empty but they also could have values.

I want all records from `NewFeatureDetails` model for which `user_id` doesn't exist in `NewFeatureRead` where:

- `current_time` is between `start` and `stop` from `NewFeature` if they exist
- or if only `start` exists I want only results where `start < current_time`
- and also if only `stop` exists I want only results where `current_time < stop`

What I tried is something like this:

```
def getNewFeatures(request):
    current_user_id = request.user.id
    new_features = NewFeatureDetails.objects.exclude(new_feature__newfeatureread__user_id=current_user_id)
    if new_features:
        features = []
        for feature in new_features:
            start = feature.new_feature.start
            stop = feature.new_feature.stop
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

            // I'm stuck here    


        return new_features
```

Is there a better way? Can it somehow be done in the query? If not, how could I do it on this way, as I tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution with 3 queries that correspond to your 3 points, and that gives a list of ids of target `NewFeature`. Then you can filter your `NewFeatureDetails` query.

```
    q1 = NewFeature.objects.filter(start__isnull=False, end__isnull=False, start__lt=current_time, end__gt=current_time)
    q2 = NewFeature.objects.filter(start__isnull=False, end__isnull=True, start__lt=current_time)
    q3 = NewFeature.objects.filter(start__isnull=True, end__isnull=False, end__gt=current_time)
    fidlist = q1.union(q2, q3).distinct().values_list('id', flat=True)
    new_features = NewFeatureDetails.objects.exclude(
        new_feature__newfeatureread__user_id=current_user_id
        ).filter(new_feature_id__in=fidlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils import timezone
NewFeatureDetails.objects.exclude(new_feature__newfeatureread__user_id=current_user_id,
                              new_feature__start__lte=timezone.now(),
                              feature__stop__gte=timezone.now() )
```

I have writtern this basic query for you. Try it out you can refine it. You can also use `__range` to filter between range of dates